# angularjs ng-repeat the dropdown values from different i18n files

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-translate

Here is an example json i18n language file for English:

```
{
  "project": {
    "SPONSORINFO": {
      "MAIN" : "Select the Sponsor Name",
      "SPONSORLIST": [
        {"spons" :"SponsorName 1" },
        {"spons" :"SponsorName 2" }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and here is my html view:

```
<div class="form-group" >
    <label for="form-field-select-1" translate="project.SPONSORINFO.MAIN">
    </label>
    <select class="form-control"  ng-model="myModel.sponsors">
       <option ng-repeat="s in projectJSON.project.SPONSORINFO.SPONSORLIST" value="{{s.spons}}">{{s.spons | translate}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

The `translate="project.SPONSORINFO.MAIN"` in the **label** is rightly showing the value  **"Select the Sponsor Name"** as soon as the language toggle is clicked (no refresh is needed).

### Question:

I am using the following function in my view controller to load the language file based on the selected language and pass it into `$scope.projectJSON` so that I can call it in `ng-repeat` in my html view:

```
var lang = $translate.use();
$http.get('assets/i18n/'+lang+'.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.projectJSON= data;
});
```

The problem is that after toggling the language, the dropdown menus don't get changed to the selected language unless I refresh or change view and come back. How can I fix this issue so that it works like the **label**?

### annex:

Translation global config in my **main.js** like the following:

```
app.config(['$translateProvider',
function ($translateProvider) {

    // prefix and suffix information  is required to specify a pattern
    // You can simply use the static-files loader with this pattern:
    $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
        prefix: 'assets/i18n/',
        suffix: '.json'
    });

    // Since you've now registered more then one translation table, angular-translate has to know which one to use.
    // This is where preferredLanguage(langKey) comes in.
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');

    // Store the language in the local storage
    $translateProvider.useLocalStorage();

}]);
```

translation config in my `mainCtrl.js`:

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$state', '$translate', 
function ($rootScope, $scope, $state, $translate) {

    $scope.language = {
        // Handles language dropdown
        listIsOpen: false,
        // list of available languages
        available: {
            'en': 'English',
            //'it_IT': 'Italiano',
            'de_DE': 'Deutsch'
        },
        // display always the current ui language
        init: function () {
            var proposedLanguage = $translate.proposedLanguage() || $translate.use();
            var preferredLanguage = $translate.preferredLanguage();
            // we know we have set a preferred one in app.config
            $scope.language.selected = $scope.language.available[(proposedLanguage || preferredLanguage)];
        },
        set: function (localeId, ev) {
            $translate.use(localeId);
            $scope.language.selected = $scope.language.available[localeId];
            $scope.language.listIsOpen = !$scope.language.listIsOpen;
        }
    };

    $scope.language.init();
```

Comment: Try to use promise pattern:

    $http.get(..).then(function(response){..})

Comment: @Vadim please write down your suggestion as a complete answer.

Comment: hey would it be possible for you put them together and put on a code snippet or plunkr, in working state to checkout?

Comment: @Mpondomise, did you solve your problem?

Comment: @Maximus not yet! I am still looking for solution. Do you have any?

Comment: @Mpondomise, so what you're saying is that after this line is executed `$scope.projectJSON= data;` the value in `<option>` tags is not updated? can you set up a plunker?

Comment: @Mpondomise , I see you are trying to read the Main label and the ng-repeat in two different ways. Main label as - project.SPONSORINFO.MAIN" and in the ng-repeat as projectJSON.project.SPONSORINFO.SPONSORLIST. is this correct?

Comment: @Sreekanth yes, I want to read my ng-repeat also like the other one. I don't want to load the language specific json separately. because it is already being automatically done for the LABEL, which is being loaded. but when it comes to ng-repeat, I can't do the same.

Comment: in that case , ng-repeat="s in projectJSON.project.SPONSORINFO.SPONSORLIST" should be ng-repeat="s in project.SPONSORINFO.SPONSORLIST" isnt it? instead of an additional projectJSON at the begining

Comment: @Sreekanth yes, but it is not working!

Comment: You should use `ng-options` in the first place.

Comment: @zeroflagL how does it change the problem? does it at all change the problem? could you suggest an answer to this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating array from translation json file. This translation json file is loaded by `$translate` service and you will not have access on loaded content, but you need the data from this json file to iterate it, thus you have to make your own request to fetch this array. Maybe you do not want but you have to make `$http.get` call.

In your code one request is made by executing this line `var lang = $translate.use(newLang);` and second call is done by `$http.get` BUT in case if `$http.get` is resolved before call in `$translate.use` is resolved It will not translate content in dropdown because request in `$translate.use` is not resolved yet and `$translate` service does not have these translations to translate.

What you can do is to listen on `$translateChangeSuccess` event (emitted by `$translate` service) on `$rootScope` and then make your ajax call in this handler.

I have tested the following code in your example and it works fine.

#### [UPDATED]

```
$rootScope.$on('$translateChangeSuccess', function () {
  // Get new current new language
  var lang = $translate.use();
  $http.get('assets/i18n/'+lang+'.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.projectJSON = data;
  });
});
```

For detailed explanation about events section on angular translate module, checkout [this link](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/18_events).

Whenever you call `$translate.use(localeId)` it will make ajax call internally and when this call is resolved it will emit `$translateChangeSuccess` event, then you make your request, load data and update `$scope.projectJSON`.
The only thing is to trigger this event first time, when you refresh browser, when `$translate.use` is not called.

For this you can just call `$translate.use` one time on page reload.

#### [UPDATED]

Put the following code at the end of your `$scope.language.init` function.

```
$translate.use(proposedLanguage || preferredLanguage);
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Basically I shouldn' need to do this $http, because the LABEL is being translated with the code in the main.js and mainCtrl.js. I am using this hack to separately load my language json again (because it is already done by main.js and mainCtrl) to feed into the dropdown menus. That's why it doesn't translate immediately, it should be refreshed. where as the LABEL is being translated on the spot.

Comment: Without additional request you won't be able to access translation data. So you have to make this request if you want to get data. May I know why do you want to show data from translation json file? What is your final purpose?

Comment: I don't want to load the translation json AT ALL! I want it to work for dropdown items as it is working for other parts of the app, without loading the json file! I have to manually load the SAME json again for dropdown menus! However, the translation is working for the titles of the table without reloading the json.

Comment: the last three lines should be included in which file? main.js , mainCtrl.js, or the view controller?
How about this line `$scope.language.selected = $scope.language.available[(proposedLanguage || preferredLanguage)]; ` should it be deleted?

Comment: actually this is working!! but, when the page is accessed for the first time after login, or in other words, without clicking on the language toggle, the dropdown menus are not loaded! they get loaded only after i toggle the language and they show the dropdown menus in the chosen language. which is fine! but they don't show unless you change the language and then afterwards it works fine! how to load the dropdown menu by default for the default language?

Comment: I don't get the point of this code here `$scope.changeLanguage = function(newLang) {
  $translate.use(newLang);
}` what is it supposed to do? whether included or not, it doesn't play any role in the story! I might be missing something here.

Comment: `$scope.changeLanguage = function(newLang) { $translate.use(newLang); }` this is doing the same as your `$scope.language.set` function, just I copied it from my example.

Comment: Last three lines should be included in your `init` method. When the page is loaded it gets language and gives to `$translate` service to make call and to load translations. Put these lines in your init method

Comment: @ZuraSekhniashvili `$scope.changeLanguage = function(newLang) { $translate.use(newLang); }`where should it be included then? it is not being called anywhere, as far as I know, what is it supposed to do? where should it go? did you read my comment above regarding the small problem on first page load and dropdown not showing until toggle is clicked?

Comment: Forget about this `$scope.changeLanguage = function(newLang) { $translate.use(newLang); }`. You do not need this. I tried my answer to be general, but I think you did not understand, so I updated my answer. Let me know if you still need help

Comment: @ZuraSekhniashvili here is how the code is looking like in the init part: http://pastebin.com/Y0GWkkJw
I am missing something?
it is giving me a GET error, `assets/i18n/English.json` not found! actually my file name is `en.json`not `English.json`

Comment: @Mpondomise try this `$translate.use(proposedLanguage || preferredLanguage);` instead of this one `$translate.use($scope.language.selected);`.

Comment: Put this `$translate.use(proposedLanguage || preferredLanguage);` at the end of init function.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use promise pattern:

```
$http.get(..).then(function(response){..})
```

So, looks like problem not in `ng-repeat`, so I would change the title of the question. Back to the subject:

```
$http.get('assets/i18n/'+lang+'.json').then(function(response) {
    //check what exactly are you getting in the response
    //console.log(response)
    $scope.projectJSON = response;
});
```

And I would check what is the `response` actually, probably, you need to do

```
$scope.projectJSON = response.data;
```

Comment: check what exactly are you getting in the `.then` function.

Answer (score 0):

**Old**

Because you are using an async function angular won't recognize the change immediately.
After downloading the files add

```
$scope.$apply();
```

To make angular rescan everything and apply changes. [Here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-$scope.$apply()) you can read more about it.

That means for you ($$phase check by @lascort)

```
$http.get('assets/i18n/'+lang+'.json').success(function(data) {
$scope.projectJSON= data;
$translate.use(lang);
if (!$scope.$$phase)
    $scope.$apply();
  $translate.refresh();
});
```

**Edit**

But official resources recommend to use their loaders and not load manually: [Here](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/12_asynchronous-loading)

You are using a staticFilesLoader so install the following extension:

`bower install angular-translate-loader-static-files`

Then in your language change function:

`$translateProvider.preferredLanguage(lang);`

This should work (says the documentation). Maybe you have to do a `$scope.$apply();` but I think this is already included.

Comment: where should I add this? Could you write a complete answer? thanks

Comment: I usually use $scope.$apply() with an if before, so it doesn't log errors when there's a digest in progress. Like so: `if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply()`

Comment: also.. on a non related matter.. `success` and `error` are deprecated. You should be using `then` and `catch`

Comment: @lascort could you write down your suggestion as an answer please? so that I can see exactly what you mean.

Comment: I added it to the answer

Comment: Astasian, your answer is not working. nor the edited version. I still have to refresh to see the chosen language's translations.

Comment: Please try this version. It seems, that you have to apply the update to $translate too.

Comment: i tried it, still no result! Only when I refresh my page or change view to another and then come back. Otherwise, when I toggle on the language button, the dropdown menus are still in the previous language.

Comment: Can you please retry it? Added $translate.use(Lang);

Comment: again, i tried your edit `$translate.use(lang);`
 , no result!

Comment: yeah I know what the official sources say. But how can I fix the problem now? What should I do exactly? I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reloading the state?

`$state.reload();`

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$state', '$translate', function ($rootScope, $scope, $state, $translate) {

$scope.language = {
    // Handles language dropdown
    listIsOpen: false,
    // list of available languages
    available: {
        'en': 'English',
        //'it_IT': 'Italiano',
        'de_DE': 'Deutsch'
    },
    // display always the current ui language
    init: function () {
        var proposedLanguage = $translate.proposedLanguage() || $translate.use();
        var preferredLanguage = $translate.preferredLanguage();
        // we know we have set a preferred one in app.config
        $scope.language.selected = $scope.language.available[(proposedLanguage || preferredLanguage)];
    },
    set: function (localeId, ev) {
        $translate.use(localeId);
        $scope.language.selected = $scope.language.available[localeId];
        $scope.language.listIsOpen = !$scope.language.listIsOpen;
    },
    uiReload: function(){
      $state.reload();
    }
};

$scope.language.init();
$scope.language.uiReload();    //call this for ui-router
```

Comment: I am using ui-router! what should I do?

Comment: I have updated the answer. I believe an equivalent to refreshing the state is $state.reload() as seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714655/reloading-current-state-refresh-data

Comment: my app breaks, doesn't load anymore. here is my complete controller code. http://pastebin.com/iCG4RCe2
i might have some other functions which are conflicting.

Comment: Get rid of $route and $templatecache. You may not have referenced the associated angular file nor included the ngRoute service in the app declaration. Get rid of it and only try the $state.reload();

Comment: it is not working. i might be mis-implementing the code, could you please edit the answer so that I can see exactly what you mean.

Comment: Updated the code. Can you just create a Plunker and add your code to it? https://plnkr.co/

Answer (score 0):

Lets go through step by step: 
1) The translate="project.SPONSORINFO.MAIN" in the label is rightly showing the value "Select the Sponsor Name" without refresh needed
2) the dropdown menus don't get changed to the selected language unless you refresh or change view and come back.

**So, the toggle for translation is actually working.**

But why it does not work for dropdown menus?
One thing we can note is that label for `project.SPONSORINFO.MAIN` is a static text while `s.spons` is dynamic based on value return.

The select option is being compiled first time when entering the page and not being recompiled after you toggle your languages changes. As such, when you toggle the translation, you retrieve the text, but the select option element is not being recompiled and thus not being translated on the fly till your next reentering/reload of the view.

You have few ways to solve the problem:
1) programmitically refresh the state/route once translate is complete. (quick fix but bad way)
**2) Write an angular directive that recompile the element once detect language changes. (better approach)**

An idea of how to achieve second solution:

```
var lang = $translate.use();
$http.get('assets/i18n/'+lang+'.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.projectJSON= data;
    $scope.newLanguage = $translate.use();
});

.directive('recompileLanguage', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      lang: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      $compile(element.contents())(scope);
      scope.$watch('lang', funcion (newValue, oldvalue) {
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
      });
    }
  }
});

<select recompile-language lang={{newLanguage}}> </select>
```

Comment: where should I put the directive? inside my view controller js file? or in my main.js file?
my http code is in my view controller js file.

Comment: where should I put that select element? where to put the directive? could you please give some explanation? thanks

Comment: You retain the select element on where you put initially. This is how you put the directive https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Comment: your plunker link is not complete.